# Terminology: note and "note class"

Tags: theory, terminology

In music, the term *note* sometimes refers to a note in a specific octave (like "C♯4") and sometimes to the set of all notes with the same name, regardless of octave (like "C♯"). Which terms should one use when trying to distinguish these two concepts?

Note that the terms *pitch* and *[pitch class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_class)* are not applicable here, since C♯ and D♭ are in the same pitch class, but they are *different notes* in both of the interpretations that I described above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but I think you can refer to both of these as a 'note'. C# is a note, C#4 is a note as well. If you want to be specific, you can say C#4, otherwise C# is fine

Comment: The thing is, I want to use two _different_ terms to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: You could refer to specific notes as C0, C1, C2... and the more general case as just C.  Or to be even more general you could refer to a specific note/sound as a "pitch" or "tone", perhaps.

Comment: I know I can use C0, C1, C2 in contrast with C (I even mentioned it in the original post). My question is what to call these two concepts in general. Using "pitch" or "tone" would be possible, I guess. But in my understanding, [pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_%28music%29) is something a bit different. Let me repeat it: C♯4 and D♭4 are different _notes_, but we hear them as the same _pitch_.

Comment: I actually think "note class" is a great way to refer to all C#s, though you might need to define it up front.  "Specific note" may work for C#4 et al, depending on the context/phrasing.  Examples of where you want to use these terms might be helpful.  Some more info on the ambiguity of "note" and other terms: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/3262/28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Note' is a horribly overloaded term, since it can also be used to include duration. What you're calling 'note class', I've seen referred to as **tonal pitch class** to distinguish it from regular pitch class, as I mention (with references) in my answer here: [General procedure for determining the name of an interval given a major key / diatonic collection](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/general-procedure-for-determining-the-name-of-an-interval-given-a-major-key-di/17365#17365)